# Recursive self join Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

This is for a redshift table so the WITH RECURSIVE from PSQL is not available to me.

Have a table that looks like this:

```
id | current_leg | previous_leg

1   | AA         |
2   | AB         |
3   | CD         |
4   | RF         | AB
5   | AW         |
6   | FV         | AA
7   | ER         | RF
```

And I want to recursively join it on itself to basically get a count of how many previous_legs a current_leg has, or the depth of the current_leg. So for this example, the output would look like:

```
id | current_leg |count_legs
1  |    AA      |     0
2  |    AB      |     0
3  |    CD      |     0
4  |    RF      |     1
5  |    AW      |     0
6  |    FV      |     1
7  |    ER      |     2
```

Any ideas on how to approach this would be great. Have read questions that refer to recursive CTEs but not sure how to get that to work for my use case.

Thanks!

Comment: How row 7 get 2 for RF?

Comment: @doddy . . . Redshift is most definitely NOT Postgres.  For instance, this is easy to solve in Postgres using recursive CTEs.  And it is not readily solvable in Redshift.

Comment: @mkRabbani because RF itself has a previous_leg for AB.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are right, the WITH RECURSIVE is not available to me in redshift. I have updated the question. Any ideas?

Comment: Recursive CTEs are now supported in Redshift starting April 29th, 2021 using the WITH RECURSIVE syntax so the original approach would now work.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/amazon-redshift-announces-support-for-heirarchical-data-queries-with-recursive-cte/ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html#r_WITH_clause-recursive-cte

Answer (score 0):

This following script giving expected results for your current sample data. You need to check this script is applicable for more data with more scenario or not-

```
SELECT A.id,A.current_leg,
CASE 
    WHEN A.previous_leg IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 
    (
        SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN B.current_leg IS NULL THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END 
        +
        CASE 
            WHEN B.previous_leg  IS NULL THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END

        FROM your_table B 
        WHERE B.id <= A.id 
        AND B.current_leg = A.previous_leg
    ) 
END Coun_legs
FROM your_table A
```